# Пунктуация при обращении

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится ли запятая при обращении перед местоимением? Например: *Доброе утро всем.* Перед именем ставится. А вот в таком случае?

Comment: А что, здесь есть обращение? Тогда бы это выглядело так: Эй, вы все, всем доброе утро!

Answer (score 1):

Людмила верно заметила: здесь обращения нет. *Доброе утро* кому? *Всем.* Дательный падеж. Запятая поэтому не нужна.

У обращения обычно форма *именительного* или *звательного* падежа. Например:

- *Доброе утро, Иван Иваныч!*
- *Привет, Вась!*

Если переписать, как у Людмилы, тогда "вы все" будет обращением (можно опустить "всем"). Или так:

> *Ребят, ну вы все, доброе утро.*

Тут и "ребят", и "вы все" будет обращениями.